# QTP: Descriptive Programing and Java Window

Tags: qtp

I am using descriptive programing in QTP 11.5, no obj repository.

I have simple web app, but there is a Java dialog window I need to open and select a checkbox before I click Run button.

Can you guys help me with the code? What I a m doing wrong?

```
Dim JavaBro, JavaDial, Jobj, JBox, JButton, JWindow

Set JavaBro = Browser("micclass:=Browser")
Set JavaDial = JavaDialog("micclass:=JavaDialog")
Set JButton = JavaButton ("micclass:=JavaButton")
Set JWindow = JavaWindow ("micclass:=JavaWindow")
Set Jobj = JavaObject("micclass:=JavaObject")
Set JBox = JavaCheckBox("micclass:=JavaCheckBox")


Set oDesc = Description.Create()
oDesc("micclass").Value = "JavaCheckBox"
JavaDialog("text:=Security Warning").JavaCheckBox("label:=I accept the risk and want to run this application\.").Set "ON"
JavaDialog("text:=Security Warning").JavaButton("text:=Run").Click
```

Comment: Please explain what is happening, and what behavior do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you don't need all the object definitions that you created on the top which you are not using it anyway.

Last two lines are enough to identify and click on the Run button.

would like to understand if the Java Dialog has parent? for example if it's on Browser or direct parent?

If it doesn't have parent your code should work like this, with proper output of where it has gone wrong.  For QTP to identify the objects more accurately one needs to put more relevant description in adding few unique attributes to it.  To learn unique description use object spy and add them here using ",' for seperating more than one description

```
If JavaDialog("text:=Security Warning").Exist( 5 ) Then
     If JavaDialog("text:=Security Warning").JavaCheckBox("label:=I accept the risk and want to run this application\.").Exist( 5 ) Then
           JavaDialog("text:=Security Warning").JavaCheckBox("label:=I accept the risk and want to run this application\.").Set "ON"
           If JavaDialog("text:=Security Warning").JavaButton("text:=Run").Exist( 5 ) Then
                  JavaDialog("text:=Security Warning").JavaButton("text:=Run").Click
           Else
                  MsgBox "Unable to Identify Run Button"
           End If
     Else
           MsgBox "Unable to Identify CheckBox"
     End If
Else
     MsgBox "Unable to Identify Security Dialog"
End If
```

If you had Browser as parent object use Browser object to start with on each object event statement.

Good luck